# Organism that can produce any possible sound

Tags: biology

[image]

Yes I'm talking about a living biological speaker.

An organism that can produce any physically possible sound at any frequency, at any speed and any intensity.

How would this biological speaker work? why would it be better or worse than normal vocal cords?

Comment: "Any possible" is...rather difficult, even for a machine. Would you consider something like "any sound within all organisms' hearing range"?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you explained *why* the creature needs to be able to do this. That would give us a better idea of what "all possible sounds" really means. Because that's complicated: there need to be top and bottom limits to the frequency range, then there's multiple frequencies at once, waveforms, phasing, and lots more - I don't know that much about audio.

Comment: In addition to the frequency/intensity limits mentioned above, how long can it hold a tune without needing to breathe? Lung capacity is a major issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to take your question.

**Perfect Imitation**
So the title of this video should say it all: [World's Weirdest - Bird Mimics Chainsaw, Car Alarm and More](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjAcyTXRunY)

The Lyre bird is capable of some amazing imitations that put the more well-known parrot to shame.

If this is what you're going for, it already exists!

(Note: here's another cool video: [Lyre bird in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTiAAHvwU8U))

**Actual Any Possible Sound**

> In physics, sound is a vibration that propagates as a typically audible mechanical wave of pressure and displacement, through a medium such as air or water. 
>   - Wikipedia

With that definition and "any frequency, any speed, and any intensity" we just fell outside the realm of any speaker made by man. In fact, since you're dealing with absolutes, I'm not sure if this is physically possible. I'm not even sure how we'd get to this point, but I would think that at some point extreme frequencies/intensities would energize molecules and atoms so much that their bonds would be destroyed. And then bad things happen.

Comment: I'm imagining a lyre bird that can cause earthquakes with its voice.

Comment: Maybe it can!  Great story seed there.  The Grimwalds visit San Andreas with their pet Lyre Bird...  Wally World surfs to Hawaii.